# In MS Teams Navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is not working for the screen share

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

We have loaded an external website (which allows the user to make or recieve phone calls) as a personal tab in MS teams. In the app, the user want to share the screen while they are in the active call. But in the teams navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is throwing permission denied error. Is there any workaround or solution to enable the screen share option for the personal tabs in teams?

Answer (score 0):

Currently teams tab supports only Camera, Microphone, Location, Notification. This is by design.